# Using status in IVY, works for the "less stable one" (ie integration), not for the other (ie milestone and release)

Tags: ant, ivy

I am trying desperately to have this working. I've spent the whole day on it and can't find what's wrong.

It seems that IVY can resolve only the "less stable status" in the statuses list, ie for the default ones, only integration not milestone or release.

This is a test ant file.

```
<project name="helicopter" basedir="." xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
    <ivy:settings file="ivysettings.xml" id="ivy.instance"/>
    <!-- the call to resolve is not mandatory, retrieve makes an implicit call if we don't -->
    <ivy:resolve file="ivy.xml" />
    <ivy:retrieve type="swc" pattern="../libs/bin/[module]-[revision].[ext]" />
    <ivy:retrieve type="src" pattern="../libs/src/[module]-[revision].[ext]" />
</project>
```

This is the ivysettings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="local" />

    <resolvers>
        <filesystem
            name="local"
            checkmodified="true">
            <artifact pattern="C:/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]" />
        </filesystem>
   </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

And this is the ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd"
>

    <info
        organisation="com.org"
        module="moduleA"
        status="integration"
    />

    <publications>
        <artifact type="swf" ext="swf" />
        <artifact type="src" ext="src.zip" />
    </publications>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="com.org" name="moduleB" rev="latest.integration">
            <artifact name="moduleB" type="swc" ext="swc" />
            <artifact name="moduleB" type="src" ext="src.zip" />
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

And the moduleB ivy.xml in the repository (folder)

```
<info organisation="com.org" module="moduleB" revision="0.0.5.0" status="integration" publication="20111201174403"/>

<publications>
    <artifact type="swc" ext="swc"/>
    <artifact type="src" ext="src.zip"/>
</publications>

<dependencies>
</dependencies>
```

So this will work, the moduleB will be downloaded all right.

Now if I edit the ivy.xml to get the latest.milestone

```
    <info
        organisation="com.org"
        module="moduleA"
        status="integration"
    />

    <publications>
        <artifact type="swf" ext="swf" />
        <artifact type="src" ext="src.zip" />
    </publications>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="com.org" name="moduleB" rev="latest.milestone">
            <artifact name="moduleB" type="swc" ext="swc" />
            <artifact name="moduleB" type="src" ext="src.zip" />
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

and edit the ivy.xml of my published moduleB (so editing in the repository folder) to be of status milestone

```
<info organisation="com.org" module="moduleB" revision="0.0.5.0" status="milestone" publication="20111201174403"/>

<publications>
    <artifact type="swc" ext="swc"/>
    <artifact type="src" ext="src.zip"/>
</publications>

<dependencies>
</dependencies>
```

it won't work, the artifact won't be found, although listed

```
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: com.org#moduleB;latest.milestone

    ==== local: tried

      -- artifact com.org#moduleB;latest.milestone!moduleB.src.zip(src):

      C:/repository/com.org/moduleB/revision]/moduleB.src.zip

      [0.0.5.0 (MD)]

      -- artifact com.org#moduleB;latest.milestone!moduleB.swc:

      C:/repository/com.org/moduleB/[revision]/moduleB.swc

      [0.0.5.0 (MD)]
```

Now the FUN PART!
Before using the defaults statuses from IVY I used mine.
It had the exact same behavior (that's why I tried the defaults one then).
The fun bits is that if I had

```
<statuses default="status-dev">
    <status name="status-stable" integration="false"/>
    <status name="status-test" integration="false"/>
    <status name="status-dev" integration="true" />
</statuses>
```

The only latest.[status] working will be for status-dev.
Now if I change the status order to

```
<statuses default="status-dev">
    <status name="status-stable" integration="false"/>
    <status name="status-dev" integration="true" />
    <status name="status-test" integration="false"/>
</statuses>
```

The only one working will be status-test.

I' puzzled here... :/

Thanks for any help you could provide.
Cheers,
Xavier

I have created a basic project showing the weird behavior.
`moduleB` is the module being published.
`moduleA` is the module getting `moduleB` as a dependency.
Please update the path to the local repository in both `ivysettings` file
The link to download the file
https://rapidshare.com/files/1326835940/test_ivy.zip

Comment: If you played around with the statuses it might help to clear the ivy-cache. Maybe the cache contains an older version of the ivy.xml.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the comment, but alas, I've cleared the cache many many times, manually or through a ant task <ivy:cleancache />.
Thank you for the comment though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, that looks like a very strange overloading of the dependency construct. I would stick with a simpler ivy.xml, with a single dependency upon moduleB. Just change the rev attribute at runtime using a property file. That is, coalesce all of your dependencies into:

```
   <dependency org="com.org" name="moduleB" rev="${dependency.rev.moduleB}" 
     conf="build-release->default;build-milestone->default;build-devs->default">
            <artifact name="shared" type="swc" ext="swc" />
            <artifact name="shared" type="src" ext="src.zip" />
   </dependency>
```

You can even supply a default value to the property (for IvyDE, for example) in your ivy-settings.xml:

```
<property name="dependency.rev.moduleB" 
          value="latest.integration"
          override="false"/>
```

Also, you'll want to edit your ivysettings.xml to include a pattern for the repository to find ivy.xml files:

```
 <resolvers>
        <filesystem
            name="local"
            checkmodified="true">
            <artifact pattern="C:/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]" />
            <ivy pattern="C:/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml" />
        </filesystem>
   </resolvers>
```

Comment: Yes I agree it's a strange one. I tried setting up the revision in a property file. Same result... Only the last status in the statuses definition can be resolved...

Comment: I have updated the question to have as simple example as I could, behavior is still the same though. Thx

Comment: so the missing ivy pattern was the culprit? The info in your edit was quite interesting, you should have posted that info and a link to the bug here, too.

Comment: @zeflasher it was adressed at kirby, he wrote in his edit comment: "Addressed bug in ivysettings.xml which prevented discovery of latest module revisions"

Comment: @oers I didn't mean to imply there was an *IVY* bug, just a bug in zeflasher's ivysettings.xml configuration.